# problems using tikzmath

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to repeat a drawing but rotated 90 degrees. I am trying to use tikzmath but can't figure it out.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    motorcoil/.style={
        decorate, decoration={coil, aspect=0.2, amplitude=20 mm,  segment length=2mm}, gray, very thick
    }
]  

  \tikzmath{
    coordinate \r1, \r2;
    real \th;
    \th = 0.0;
    for \k in {0,1}
    {
      \r1 = (\th : 2.5);
      \r2 = (\th : 4.4);
      \draw [motorcoil, color=red] (\r1) -- (\r2);
      \th = \th + 90;
    };

  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get an error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.} (followed by: )  line 27 pos -1
```

But this works fine:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    motorcoil/.style={
        decorate, decoration={coil, aspect=0.2, amplitude=20 mm,  segment length=2mm}, gray, very thick
    }
]  

  \coordinate (r1) at (0 : 2.5);
  \coordinate (r2) at (0 : 4.4);
  \draw [motorcoil, red] (r1) -- (r2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What did I do wrong? Or is there another way to repeat a drawing rotated 90 degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have a spurious space following `for \k in {0,1}` before the opening `{` which is throwing the parser. Remember that a new line is a space for TeX.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    font=\sffamily,
    motorcoil/.style={%
      decorate,
      decoration={coil, aspect=0.2, amplitude=20 mm,  segment length=2mm},
      gray,
      very thick
    }
  ]
  \tikzmath{
    coordinate \r1, \r2;
    real \th;
    \th = 0.0;
    for \k in {0,1}%
    {
      \r1 = (\th : 2.5);
      \r2 = (\th : 4.4);
      {%
        \draw [motorcoil, color=red] (\r1) -- (\r2);
      };
      \th = \th + 90;
    };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: unspaced TikZ maths]

Comment: um.... where is the space?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: thanks. (GAAH! TeX and Tikz drives me BONKERS in some way almost every time I try to use it.)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the TikZ `math` library, so I initially assumed this would be obvious once stated, if you see what I mean, even though I identified it as a problem myself by a process of brute force ;).

Comment: they are only obvious if you use them every day :/

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that's right. I guess I assumed you were very familiar with the library's syntax as you seemed to know how to make it do something, which I didn't ;). Anyway, I've clarified it now so thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2):

grr, I did it another way with `\begin{scope}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    motorcoil/.style={
        decorate, decoration={coil, aspect=0.2, amplitude=20 mm,  segment length=2mm}, gray, very thick
    }
]  

  \foreach\color [count=\k] in {red, blue}
  {
   \begin{scope}[rotate=90*\k]
   \coordinate (r1) at (0 : 2.5);
   \coordinate (r2) at (0 : 4.4);
   \draw [motorcoil, color=\color] (r1) -- (r2);
   \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ARGH -- except now I get a NoViableAltException in line 17 at position 26. Is some \end command missing?

Comment: Though this code works fine for me.

Comment: It does answer the question, it just takes another way of doing it instead. Please don't delete. Downvote if you don't think it's a good answer, but if someone finds the question then maybe they will benefit from this answer.

Comment: changed question

Comment: Good ! And I don't want to down-vote it. Actually, I up-voted it when I realised you weren't really continuing your question here, as I'd first thought. Your initial comment is curious, though. Do you really get an error with this code? Because it works fine for me.

Comment: I figured it out, but then later I forgot what it was that I figured out. TeX syntax is so fragile!